# How to assign a long hex value, what data type should I assigned it to in Java?

Tags: java, variables

I want to assign the below hex value as a variable, what datatype should I choose to use?

`5C6847CA179309189D68679F8A77C3192577A242D5FF053F72F0E1A3F754191B8B0819BD367711F8195A4DA5FDE8F7EBFB12606DB3A1685DD92AF2126836D20F`

Doesn't seems like assigning long with "L" works.

Comment: `long` won't work here, try `BigInteger`.

Comment: If you are going to do any mathematical operations with that value, `BigInteger` as previously suggested. Otherwise, `String` would do. Which data type you should use depends on what you want to do with the value, as much as on what value you want to store.

Comment: The answer depends on what you want to do with it. Can you please describe in detail how the value will be used and what operations you want to perform with it etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `long` has a maximum of 64-bits, your number has way more than 64 bits.

To convert it to a `BigInteger` use: `BigInteger(String val, int radix)` where radix is 16 (for hex).

> **BigInteger(String val, int radix)**
> Translates the String representation of a BigInteger in the specified radix into a BigInteger.

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("5C6847CA179309189D68679F8A77C3192577A242D5FF053F72F0E1A3F754191B8B0819BD367711F8195A4DA5FDE8F7EBFB12606DB3A1685DD92AF2126836D20F",16);

String value = "5C6847CA179309189D68679F8A77C3192577A242D5FF053F72F0E1A3F754191B8B0819BD367711F8195A4DA5FDE8F7EBFB12606DB3A1685DD92AF2126836D20F";
System.out.println((bi.toString(16)));
System.out.println(value.toLowerCase().compareTo(bi.toString(16)));
System.out.println(value.compareTo(bi.toString(16).toUpperCase()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html

`long` doesn't work here. The max `long` value is (2^63)-1.
Try to use `BigInteger`.